# BokehJS library missing error and no plot

Tags: bokeh, holoviews, bokehjs

I am running Anaconda 10.0 Jupyter Notebook Python 3.8, bokeh 2.3.0 on Chrome. On my other PC (should be identical setup, except this is a slightly later Anaconda version) images are fine, but on this there is no image and the Javascript console tells me:

> Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing

I could not find a simple, working solution to this problem here or elsewhere on the net and I am at a total loss now.

The abbreviated code I'm running is:

```
import regex as rg
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import datashader as ds, colorcet
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade
from holoviews import opts

hv.extension("bokeh")
datashade(hv.Points(df_re), cmap=colorcet.fire).relabel('Reflectances').opts(height=700, width=800)
```

Where is the problem and how should I fix it?

Comment: I am seeing the same JS error and have posted the following to the holoviews issue tracker: https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues/4861

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that didn't work for me, still the same error.

What I found interesting was that prior to installing ver. 1.0.3 of the extension, Anaconda prompt said:

```
(Datashader-Holoview) C:\Windows\system32>jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v2.2.6
No installed extensions
```

It is as if no version of that extension did exist in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a bug with the most recent pyviz jupyter labextension (1.0.4).  See if it works for you after you do

`jupyter labextension install @pyviz/jupyterlab_pyviz@1.0.3`

This worked for me.

Comment: I just did a random test trying this on the base environment on Anaconda. It works, no error, plot shows up! Looking at the environments, the base has now 322 installed packages while the one I created for this test has 152 . Apparently something is missing from the new environment.

Comment: This did not work for me version and that version of pyviz seems to conflict with several dependencies if you have jupyter lab v3.0.11